# Click FlatList data ... clickable data appear top of the FlatList

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
const Home = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(1);

  const managedList = [
    { name: "John Doe1" },
    { name: "John Doe2" },
    { name: "John Doe3" },
    { name: "John Doe4" },
    { name: "John Doe5" },
    { name: "John Doe12" },
    { name: "John Doe13" },
    { name: "John Doe14" },
    { name: "John Doe15" }

  ];
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={managedList}//{managedList.slice(display - 1, display)}
        keyExtractor={mohan => mohan.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuStyle} onPress={() => {
            setDisplay(display + 1);
          }}><Text>{item.name}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        }}
      />

      {/* <Button
                title="Show Next"
                onPress={() => 
                    {
                    setDisplay(display + 1);
                }}
            /> */}
    </View>
  );
};
```

#### This is my code

**I want output like this ...**

- If I click John Doe12 data this data appear top of the page like ...
- I click John Doe12 this data come place of Josh Doe1
- and Josh Doe1 data going to place of Josh Doe2
- and Josh Doe2 data going to one step down place of Josh Doe3

#### This is my output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Use a state to store the display data. When a object is clicked, re-create an array by selected object and the remaining list.

**Function Component**

```
const managedList = [
    { name: "John Doe1" },
    { name: "John Doe2" },
    { name: "John Doe3" },
    { name: "John Doe4" },
    { name: "John Doe5" },
    { name: "John Doe12" },
    { name: "John Doe13" },
    { name: "John Doe14" },
    { name: "John Doe15" }
  ];

  const [displayList, setDisplayList] = useState(managedList);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={displayList}
        keyExtractor={mohan => mohan.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.menuStyle}
            onPress={() => {
              setDisplayList([
                item,
                ...displayList.filter(obj => obj != item)
              ])
            }}
          >
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
```

------------------------**Edit**------------------------

**Class Component**

```
export default class DemoScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayList: [
        { name: "John Doe1" },
        { name: "John Doe2" },
        { name: "John Doe3" },
        { name: "John Doe4" },
        { name: "John Doe5" },
        { name: "John Doe12" },
        { name: "John Doe13" },
        { name: "John Doe14" },
        { name: "John Doe15" }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.displayList}
          keyExtractor={mohan => mohan.name}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.menuStyle}
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                  displayList: [
                    item,
                    ...this.state.displayList.filter(obj => obj != item)
                  ]
                })
              }}
            >
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much it's  working. in function component......but how I can use in class component

Comment: Editted the answer with class component. Basically the logic is the same, just be careful about the syntax of class component in `setState`.

Comment: I want like this if I click any Flatlist data is change position and also navigate is done but whenever  I'm go back to Home screen data not chnage the position  so how can I do this??

Comment: This require other library like `async-storage` or global state library like `context` or `redux` to do so. The answer will be different according to the design of the app. So, please create another post for this question.